# How to enable or backport Bluethooth BLE feature in Linux kernel 3.10.0 version?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluez, gatt, backport

I have tried to enable bluetooth LE in my linux kernel version 3.10.0, but could find [*]   Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) features in the menuconfig.

I am trying to find backport patch for the [*]   Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) features to linux kernel version 3.10.0.

Basically I need the gatt service  since the application program interface for wechat only supports gatt api's for bluetooth.

I see the [*]   Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) features is available only  >=  kernel version 3.10.0 or precisely from 3.13 version BLE is enabled.

Please give me your idea's / reference links to enable gatt server in the linux kernel version 3.10.0.

Other option I found is to download the backport tarball and enable the BLE feature, but I couldnt find the targball any where.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually add missing source code files, modify drivers/Makefiles. You have bt support in /drivers/bluetooth and under network files